# No instance of function template

Tags: c++, pointers

I keep receiving the error No instance of function template and not sure why. The error comes up for line PersonNode* getNext() {

```
return next;
```

}

Here's my code below:
Header file

```cpp
using namespace std;
class PersonNode
{

private:
    string fName, lName, address, phone;
    PersonNode* next;

public:
    PersonNode();
    PersonNode(string fName, string lName, string address, string phone);
    string getAddress();
    string getFName();
    string getFullName();
    string getLName();
    PersonNode* getNext();
    string getPhone();
    void setAddress(string Address);
    void setFName(string FName);
    void setLName(string LName);
    void setNext(PersonNode* Next);
    void setPhone(string Phone);
};
```

cpp file

```cpp
#include "PersonNode.h"
PersonNode::PersonNode(string FName, string LName, string Address, string Phone) {
    fName = FName;
    lName = LName;
    address = address;
    phone = phone;
    next = NULL;
}

PersonNode::PersonNode() {
    next = NULL;
}

PersonNode* getNext() {

    return next;
}

void PersonNode::setNext(PersonNode *Next)
{
    next = Next;
}
```

Comment: You receive the error in *what* code? Is this a template class or struct?

Comment: This is a class sorry I'm new on here.

Comment: Is it a *template* class? Can you show more of the class definition?

Comment: Code like that is a wreck in the comments. Just edit the question to include it and try and format it. Tip: The `{}` button helps.

Comment: Also worth including the code that generated the error, plus the *exact* error text which often includes contextual information.

Comment: Ok I updated it. The error is for the getNext(). It underlines the next for the return

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's typeless `NULL`. It's also worth making your getters in the pattern of `const std::string& getX() const` so that it doesn't make copies. Also, use [constructor lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: Is the error for the `getNext()` definition, or some call elsewhere to that function?

Comment: no the error is for the getNext(). it says C++ no instance of function template matches the required type. red line under next

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your prefix:

```cpp
PersonNode* PersonNode::getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

This was being declared as a function independent from the class. As such there's no `next` to latch on to, it's not a thing.

Note for trivial functions like this it's often better to declare them in the body of the class. That also helps the compiler inline calls like this, as they really are some extremely minimal code.

Comment: thank you! I'll start doing that moving forward.

Comment: Another tip: Instead of mangling your argument names to avoid conflicts, just do `void PersonNode::setNext(PersonNode *next) { this->next = next; }` to work around the variable shadowing issue.

Comment: Yeah that's another good tip I'm going to try to get more comfortable doing that.